# Can I open and edit a point shapefile from another point shapefile

Tags: arcpad

If out in the field gathering points in one shapefile with its own attribute table is it possible to create a form that will allow you to gather a point with a different attribute table

For example:

If I am gathering points on a pipeline which has its own attributes and I come across a valve which has its own attributes can I open the valve layer for editing from the Pipeline layer?

I have eleven different shapefiles but they are all associated with pipeline I would like to make a form that lets me fill in the attributes for a pipeline then click a button for the valve layer or any of the other layers then go back to pipeline

Comment: sounds like you should probably move everything from shapefiles to a geodatabase

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend converting your 11 shapefiles into a file geodatabase. Doing so will give you much finer control over your data and allow you to create coded value domains, which will help normalize your data. Once in a geodatabase, you should be able to switch back and forth based on which feature class you are collecting (pipeline vs valve).

Here is a good tool you can use to [convert your shapefiles](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcpad/10.2/app/index.html#//00s1000000wv000000).

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet in switching layers it to use the [QuickCapture toolbar](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcpad/10.0/help/index.html#//00s10000007w000000). The QuickCapture toolbar can be thought of as a list of all the layers in your project - similar to the Table of Contents panel in ArcMap. Once you've put your layers on the map the QuickCapture toolbar will be populated with symbol categories (which you can modify later), and selecting from the symbology should allow you to quickly switch layers.